# Creating a new table with cumsum - code doesn't seem to be working?

Tags: r, dplyr

So I am using dplyr to create a new data frame to plot: `date` in column 1, `IDCount` in column 2 and `CumulativeIDCount` in column 3. Here is the code that I am using to do it:

```
df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(Date)%>%
  summarise(IDCount =n(),CumulativeIDCount=cumsum(n()))
```

but the `cumulativeIDCount` column isn't cumulative, it's exactly the same as the `IDCount` column. Where am I going wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably what you need is `cumsum` of `IDCount` after the grouping

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Date)%>%
  summarise(IDCount =n()) %>%
  mutate(CumulativeIDCount = cumsum(IDCount))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(IDCount = .N), Date][, CumulativeIDCount = cumsum(IDCount)][]
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   count(Date) %>%
   mutate(CumulativeIDCount = cumsum(n))
```